# how to set textview horizontally inside linearlayout

Tags: android

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorSlate"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hello"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#5d737e"
                        android:padding="20dp"
                        android:text="₹ 250.00"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/world"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
                    android:onClick="@{()->upgradeViewModel.gotoPremimum()}"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                        android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                        android:text="Go premium"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="14.4sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_white"

                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml i am trying to display text horizontally in first linear-layout but when i try to insert another text-view below text-view inside linear-layout i am my first linear-layout get increase not fit with second layout please suggest me how to achieve this  i want set text below 200 in given screen

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, atleast to me . Edit your question (May be  attach image expected result and current result)

Comment: https://snag.gy/cXfjbk.jpg  i want  set textview below 200 @ADM

Comment: Below 200 ? Where pls point out in image .

Comment: https://snag.gy/KD6YdJ.jpg expected @ADM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"


        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#5d737e"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="₹ 250.00"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#5d737e"
           android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="₹ 250.00"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/world"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:onClick="@{()->upgradeViewModel.gotoPremimum()}"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            android:text="Go premium"

            android:textSize="14.4sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".5"


            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout below . I have changes some attributes to default you can reset them as per your requirement.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue_end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="₹ 250.00"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subscription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Subscription"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            android:text="Go premium"
            android:textSize="14.4sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#5d737e"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="₹ 250.00"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yearly Subscription"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/world"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="@{()->upgradeViewModel.gotoPremimum()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:text="Go premium"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14.4sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="14dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_white"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

try this. :)